# ShouldSerialize* methods are not called in Web API documentation using SWAGGER

Tags: asp.net-web-api, json.net, swagger

I am using Swagger for Web API documentation.
In my Web API, I have entities as below:

```
public class BaseEntity
{
    public string BaseEntProp1{get;set;}
    public string BaseEntProp2{get;set;}

    public virtual bool ShouldSerializeBaseEntProp1()
    {
         return true;
    }

    public virtual bool ShouldSerializeBaseEntProp1()
    {
         return true;
    }
}

public class DerivedEntity1 : BaseEntity
{
    [JsonIgnore]
    public string DerEntProp1{get;set;}

    public string DerEntProp2{get;set;}

    public override bool ShouldSerializeBaseEntProp1()
    {
         return false;
    }

    public override bool ShouldSerializeBaseEntProp1()
    {
         return false;
    }
}
```

I used DerivedEntity1 as the input parameter for a Web API method and generated the swagger documentation.

Until this it is fine but the problem is, DerivedEntity1 JSON string in that documentation shows both BaseEntProp1 & BaseEntProp2 which are supposed to be excluded. Can someone help me how to exclude those?

Note:
1. DerivedEntity1's DerEntProp1 property is properly excluded.
2. Just to confirm, in my Startup method after the documentation is generated, I have hardcoded following:

```
    var temp = new DerivedEntity1 { 
                   BaseEntProp1 = "should be ignored", 
                   BaseEntProp2 = "this also should be ignored"};

    string tempJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(temp);
```

Above test passed, i.e., tempJson doesn't have both BaseEntProp1 & BaseEntProp2. So, I suspect somehow SWAGGER is failing to call proper ShouldSerialize* methods. Any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Finally I solved it in a different way as the problem is not related to Swagger.

I have created base abstract classes with virtual properties. In derived classes I have overloaded those properties and decorated with JsonIgnore attribute. This solved my problem.